# Why was my flag rejected?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I am new to review. Why was my flag rejected?  I flagged this question...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530928/use-perl-to-remove-column-from-sql-insert

...with "Should be closed: in the comments, the asker tells us that the question isn't valid."

I got back "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention."

Huh?  Yes, please, take action and close the question.  What am I missing?

Comment: Don't flag for moderator attention unless it requires moderator attention. That flag is like the `911` of Stack Overflow.

Comment: So what should I have done? See comment trail below.

Comment: @Compass I agree with you, but strangely enough, the reason for declining wasn't "Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster...".

Comment: @Anonymous flags were very different 7 years ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have voted to close the flag for the appropriate close reason, not flagged for moderator attention telling them to close the question.

Question closures, outside of highly unusual cases (which this is not) are handled by regular community members, not moderators.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do.  How do I vote to close?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Choose the "this question should be closed [...]" option.

Comment: And what do I click on to do that? There is no "close" link. For example, on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530928/use-perl-to-remove-column-from-sql-insert

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski You click "flag".

Comment: *sigh*  That's what I did to get this result.  What should I then click after that, in order to vote to close and express the reason "Should be closed: in the comments, the asker tells us that the question isn't valid"?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski You choose to cast the wrong *type* of flag after choosing to flag.  You choose to cast a custom moderator flag, rather than selecting the option stating that the question should be closed.

Comment: I am confused.  What is "Cast" here?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski The flag.

Comment: What does it mean to cast a flag?  Does "Cast" mean send, or change type, or something else?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski When you click on "flag", then choose the appropriate reason, and click the submit button, you will have cast a flag.

Comment: OK, I will trust you on that one.  Anyway, what reason should I choose if I want to express the reason "Should be closed: in the comments, the asker tells us that the question isn't valid"?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Look at the valid reasons for voting to close a question and see which one(s) you think apply.  That the OP thinks the question isn't valid isn't a reason to close the question.  The reason that the OP has stated the question isn't valid may be a reason to close the question.

Comment: OK, what option would you choose?

Comment: Probably `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.`

Comment: So you are saying that, if clarification discussion in comments reveals a question to be invalid, that is the same as being not a good enough example for debugging?  Wouldn't that reason, though, be seen as not correct, and thus the close vote would get reviewed and overturned?

Comment: No, I'm saying that that question doesn't explain the problem with his code, and apparently the code doesn't even have a problem (therefore it fails to provide a reproducible example).

Comment: Seems like a stretch, and would confuse the OP and future visitors more than help them.

Comment: If you don't think the reason applies, then don't use it.  It's your flag, you're free to choose whichever reason (if any) you feel is appropriate.

Comment: Others are saying I did the wrong thing, but no one can tell me the right thing.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I state as much right in the answer.  You should have flagged the question for closure, not for moderator attention.  That is the proper course of action.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I know it's a little late, but here's exact instructions: 1. Click "Flag" 2. Choose "needs improvement" from the list 3. Select the option that you want to close it for 4. Click "Flag question"

Comment: I'm done trying to learn the right shibboleth.  I haven't done much reviewing in the last few years and I don't think I'm going to start.

Answer (score 6):

I was the moderator that reviewed the flag and I declined it because we don't need to be involved with this question.

Moderators should only be involved in things that the community can't handle.  In this case, you used an "other" flag asking that a moderator close the question. You should use the standard close votes or close flags to request a question be closed. Those flags/votes will go into the review queue and the community will take care of it.

Comment: Sounds like the problem isn't with that policy, but rather with the UX to express this.  I could find no other option that fit.