# Can't go to Triage because "Too many of my flags are declined"

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, triage, flag-ban

I've become active on StackOverflow very recently. I started reviewing posts through 'review' link on the top and flagged several posts on Triage.

[image]

Yup I might have committed mistakes in the beginning. But today I noticed in my **flag-summary** that most of my flags are accepted.

And the bigger issue is, even when my flags were declined, the actual posts are **[on hold]** right now. That demonstrates that my flags were TRUE but declined.

[image]
In the image, these questions are either ON HOLD or REMOVED, though my flags are declined. So in short, these moderators are saying that I'm insincere even though flagging the right questions. In fact, most of my flagged questions are either on hold or removed.

What am I doing wrong here? And how can I get privilege to access Triage again?

Comment: You're misusing custom moderator flags; you should flag for closure instead. What do you expect a mod to do here?

Comment: The decline reason *tells you the problem*. These questions should have been flagged as **should be closed...**, not **in need of moderator intervention**; they can and should be dealt with by the community without involving moderators. See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249687/248731

Comment: @gnat: How is _"I can't access the triage queue"_ a duplicate of _"I can't close-vote because I lack rep"_?

Comment: @Cerbrus OP is blocked from triage because of declined flags; did you check the answer in the question I referred? it explains why custom flags to close are typically declined. Worth noting that it is in turn a duplicate of [Why was my flag rejected?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280042/839601) that covers the same issue

Comment: you will likely gain access to triage after [meta-tag:flag-suspension] ends, it typically takes about a week

Comment: Then I think the second one is a better duplicate.

Comment: @Cerbrus maybe; I picked this one because it seems to better serve under-3K users willing to participate in closing but doing it the wrong way

Comment: @gnat thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that you're using *custom flags* for simple close-vote reasons.

When you raise a custom flag, *only moderators* can handle it. Unless a question absolutely requires moderator intervention, you really don't want to get them involved. They've got enough flags to take care of as it is.

When you see a low quality post, downvote it, comment on it, edit it, or [(if / when you can)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) close-vote it.
Custom flags are generally frowned upon for cases that don't require moderators to get involved, and as such, often declined.

To access the Triage queue again, you're going to have to flag more posts for *good* reasons. Having a larger ratio of accepted : rejected flags should get you your access back, in time.

Comment: Ohhh I'm still a newly active user and used to feel 'moderators know more and they should handle' while flagging them for moderators.